# Is it possible to use the default android loading animations on an ImageView?

Tags: android, image, loading, imageview

I know android uses their own loading animations through that are included with the android.jar...however I have not been able to successfully get them to work with an ImageView correctly.  For instance, the following code gives me an error in my xml file that says the image is not public...is there anyway to get this to work correctly or is it even possible?

```
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/loadingImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="6px"
        android:paddingLeft="6px" android:src="@android:drawable/spinner_white_16">
    </ImageView>
```

I know its possible to slice a loading gif up and use `animation-list` however it would be convenient to just use android's images.

Comment: Shame, it seems like it's really a private resource. I also had intentions to use this drawable.